# Compose Layout - display text in middle and card at bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to display a text in the middle of the screen and a card at the bottom.
Both text and card should not exceed the screen. Half of the second column exceeds the screen. Why? How to fix this? Thx

```
Box(
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(Color.Transparent),
) {
  Column(
       Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
  ) {
     Text(
        “Some title and subtitle",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        color = Color.White,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 30.sp
     )
      Column(
         Modifier
        .height(100.dp)
        .width(100.dp),
         verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
      ) {
        //some other text and button
       }
    }
    
  Column(
       modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding( 15.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
   ) {
        Text(
        “Some text",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        color = Color.White,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 15.sp,
         )  
            //some text abd image
          
        }
```

} }

Comment: With your code both texts are displayed at top of the screen, and none exceeds the screen. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov i did update the code. thx for your notice!!

Comment: I still [can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVo3P.png) whole text

Comment: If you're using [Accompanist Insets](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/insets) with `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` you may need `.systemBarsPadding()` modifier

Answer (score 0):

```
 Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Transparent),
) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            "Some title and subtitle",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 30.sp
        )
        Column(
            Modifier
                .height(100.dp)
                .width(100.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            //some other text and button
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(15.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
    ) {
```

> i have added the card below

```
        Card(elevation = 10.dp, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(
                "Some text",
                Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                        textAlign = TextAlign . Center,
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 15.sp,
            )
            //some text abd image
        }
    }
}
```

> this is the image iam getting i dont know if it sloves your problem

[image]